# Script bash para hacer copia de un directorio en recursivo

Tags: linux, bash, script, git-bash

Tengo este script en bash para hacer copias de seguridad de unos directorios html pero quiero excluir lo siguiente :

- Directorio node_modules/ y vendor/ de los distintos proyectos que existen
- Directorio .git de cada proyecto.
- Directorio entero con esta ruta --> /var/www/html/ftp/cars

Para ello tengo este código...hago un tar con verbose para ver por pantalla lo que me hace y me pone absolutamente todo, el directorio .git...y los directorios node_modules y vendor.

```
#!/bin/bash

# What to backup.
backup_files="/var/www/html"

# Where to backup to.
dest="/home/debian/backups/local/www"

# Create archive filename.
#day=$(date +%A)
day=`date +%Y%m%d"_"%H"_"%M"_"%S`
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="www-$hostname-$day.tgz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $backup_files to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar czf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files --exclude-vcs --exclude='**/node_modules/*' --exclude='**/vendor/*' --exclude=/var/www/html/ftp/cars

# Print end status message.
echo
echo "Backup finished"
date

# Long listing of files in $dest to check file sizes.
#ls -lh $dest
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos grandes trucos / mañas / trampas en el comando tar que toca hacer (y una aclaración):

1. Hay que poner exclude al comienzo de la instrucción pa que la tenga en cuenta al hacer lo que sea que haga. Mejor dicho, tiene que estar antes que le digas cuál es el directorio que va a guardar en el tar y cuál es el archivo destino.
2. No hay que usar *trailing slashes* en los directorios. Si no quieres incluir `/node_modules`, no tienes que decirle que excluya `/node_modules/`.
3. Si usas `**/node_modules/*`, con el asterisco al final, te va a dejar el directorio vacío. ¿Es eso lo que buscas?

Entonces, sería algo como:

```
# Backup the files using tar.
tar --exclude-vcs --exclude='**/node_modules' --exclude='**/vendor' --exclude='/var/www/html/ftp/cars' -czf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files
```